# How to pass HTML code in query string

Tags: javascript, ajax

I need to pass html code with QueryString because im using ajax method to send post(i mean comment not the type of method) on my web site. When I write a post like that.

```
"Hi everybody<br />Whats'up."
```

its just taking "Hi everybody" removing rest of the content.

Info : Im using GET Method

Comment: POST semantics doesn't pass parameters on query string. so this question is somewhat confusing.

Comment: You can get some value back also with POST.
The question to ask yourself when choosing between GET and POST is: does the query changes the state of the server?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't use `escape`, it's a deprecated function.  Use [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Functions/encodeURIComponent) instead:

```
encodeURIComponent("Hi everybody<br />Whats'up.");
```

Also, don't forget about [Internet Explorer's 2,083 character limit in the address bar](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208427), you should use POST instead of GET if you want to avoid it.

Comment: Cool! I am deleting my answer then.

Comment: Ok i'm using it thank you so much..

And also thanks espacially Pablo Santa Cruz for interested in my problem.

Answer (score 0):

What method are you using - GET or POST? You should be using POST. That will allow you to send full html and you don't need to use the querystring.

Comment: +1 I see no reason for a downvote here. Suggesting POST is perfectly reasonable and moreover a preferred solution.

Comment: @Anurag: I didn't downvote, but this isn't an answer to the question and it should be a comment. Moreover, even if the OP had taken this advice the problem still stands - POST data still needs URL encoding.

Answer (score 0):

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/index.html?html_code=Hi%20everybodyWhats'up.
```