# How to pass html code in url query string

Tags: jquery, html, vue.js, query-string, urlencode

I need to pass a html message through url query string. But i am getting error. I have tried encodeURIComponent() , encodeURI(), escape()

```
    var uriMessage = encodeURIComponent("<p>This is my test message..</p>");
    window.open("/controller/action?param=" + uriMessage, "_blank");
```

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Show an example if the uriMessage variable please

Comment: @wasanga7, Question updated

Comment: Maybe this wil [help](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3204879/7430022)

Comment: Please post the error.

Comment: Getting what error?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to encode html somehow, the simple window.open should work. Without knowing what error do you receive it is pretty hard to tell what do you issue.
Also please take a note that the maximum request length for GET requests are pretty short, as you can see in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659952/maximum-length-of-http-get-request), so sending raw html in a query string does not look like a clean solution.